# How to get all redirects to a page in Wiki API?

Tags: api, redirect, wiki, wikipedia-api

I need all names(redirects) for a title.
Example: for title "European Court of Human Rights" I need redirects list:

- Cour européenne des droits de l’homme
- European Human Rights Court
- European Court for Human Rights
- European court of human rights
- Court for Human Rights
- Strasbourg Court
- Strasbourg court
- ECtHR
- Grand Chamber of the European Court of Human Rights
- Criticism of the European Court of Human Rights
- Criticism of ECtHR
- European Court on Human Rights

any ideas?

request sample: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&redirects=true&titles=Strasbourg%20Court&format=xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `backlinks` module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aBacklinks) and set its `bffilterredir` parameter to `redirects`:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=backlinks&blfilterredir=redirects&bltitle=European%20Court%20of%20Human%20Rights&bllimit=max